# How to assign a map path to a string in c#, mvc

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, smtp, server.mappath

I'm sending attached mail with my web project.I use following code to give the local path

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/EmailStyle/TD-emailForCus.html")))
            {
                body = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

then this works properly.but I want to do like this.

```
stirng mypath = stirng.Format("~/EmailStyle/TD-emailForCus.html");
 using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath(mypath)))
                {
                    body = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
```

when I do this, it does not work properly.how can I give a map path like this.hope your help.thanx.

Comment: when i use  break point in stream reader line. its go through it. but then execute was stopped..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do like this.get your full `Server.MapPath()` to a variable like this and then call it,

```
var mypath = Server.MapPath("~/EmailStyle/TD-emailForCus.html");
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(mypath))
            {
                body = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

this will help to you.